# Lightning Components for Visualforce firing events

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am tring to fire a lightning application event from a component being loaded by Lightning Components for Visualforce. 
Here is the event

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="Event template">
  <aura:attribute name="id" type="String"/>
</aura:event>
```

In my component I have

```
<aura:registerEvent name="getId" type="c:DWRE_getId"/>
```

My helper I have

```
var getProductsEvent = $A.get("e.c:DWRE_getId");
```

However getProductsEvent is always undefined. Is it possible to fire application level events from components being loaded in VF user LCfVF?

Don

Comment: Its definitely possible .Whats your event name that you have declared ?

Comment: Also share the detailed code .For lightning components always give as detail as possible so that its a step easier to debug

Answer (score 11):

There is a blog post [here](http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.com/2016/02/lightning-events-via-visualforce.html) with the below working example where clicking the button fires the event and then the event is handled on the visualforce page:

-- Component --

```
<aura:component>
  <div> Hello World !!!! </div>
   <aura:registerEvent name="myevent" type="c:myEvent" />
  <ui:button label="fireEvent" press="{!c.fireevent}" />
</aura:component>
```

-- Component Controller --

```
({
    fireevent: function(component, event, helper) {
        var myEvent = $A.get("e.c:myEvent");
        myEvent.setParams({"data":"Test"});
        myEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

-- Application Event --

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION">
  <aura:attribute type="string" name="data" />
</aura:event>
```

-- Lightning App --

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
  <aura:dependency resource="c:myComponent" />
</aura:application>
```

-- Visualforce Page --

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="lightning"> Hello world VF ..!!! </div>
    <script>

        $Lightning.use("c:myEventApp", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:myComponent", {}, "lightning", function(){
                $A.eventService.addHandler({ "event": "c:myEvent", "handler" : visualForceFunction});

            });
        }); 

    </script>

    <script>

    var visualForceFunction = function(event){
            var myEventData = event.getParam("data");
            console.log(myEventData);
        };

    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. After checking the examples and the answers I have it working as expected.

Comment: @Jenny B thanks a petabyte. Works great with Locker Service. Used it to call console integration toolkit (close sub tab) from Lightning Component.