# Can we get the response from an Event fired inside Aura component?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

The code below is from a VisualForce page

```
$Lightning.use(“c:myLightningApp”, function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent(
            “MyComponentName”,
            {},
            “divName”,
            function(cmp) {
                      var myEvent;
                      myEvent= $A.get("e.c:MyEventNameHere");
                      myEvent.setParams({ "data": SetSomeValueHere});
                      myEvent.fire();
            });
        });
```

So what is happening here is

1. I have declared an event
2. I fire the event, This event is handled by an Aura component controller which gets data from the Apex controller.
3. Is it possible to get the value from the #2 Aura controller after the `myEvent.fire();`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lightning Components for Visualforce firing events](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/117272/lightning-components-for-visualforce-firing-events/117326)

Comment: Your VF need to set up an event listener, and the component fires it to send data back to the VF page. Arguably, there are easier ways of doing this, but if that's the design you want to use, the code in the linked answer should work.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you for the reply but not sure if my question is not clearly explained. In the example that you shared the button in the component fires the event from the component controller and is handled on the VF page using  $A.eventService.addHandler.

What I am trying to do is from the VF page, fire the event which is handled in the component controller. The component controller calls an APEX controller to get some data. I can console the data received from the APEX controller in the component controller. Next, I want to send this data back to the VF page from where I fired the event.

Comment: @Edviges You need two events. The first event is fired from page to component, as you've done. The second event is fired from the component to the page, as demonstrated in the linked Q&A. You could also choose to use [Lightning Message Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_message_channel), but that's arguably more complicated than implementing the return event at this point.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you for the reply.